# Changing user passwords in Windows Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, windows

Suppose that users in a domain aunthenticate using windows domain controller.

How can the administrator of the windows domain controller change the passwords of users?

Does this require user's consents? (I do not think so, but just to make sure..)

I want to know in Windows 2000, 2003 and 2008.

Comment: Microsoft does a [pretty good job](http://technet.microsoft.com/) of providing online documentation for Windows administration.  Have you looked to see what documentation is available?  Was something unclear, or did you try something and receive an error message?  Show us that you've tried to find the answer.

Comment: Given that you're asking for three versions of Windows server, and it sounds like you've not checked documentation before asking...is this some kind of homework question, honestly?

Answer (score 7):

To change someone's password, an admin's user account needs to be a member of the Domain Administrators or Account Operators groups. Alternatively, permission to reset passwords can be delegated to a specific user or groups.

You use the Users and Computers MMC snap-in which is available on the domain controller, or can be run from an Administrator's desktop using the adminpak.msi or by the remote server administration toolset.

Most of what you will need to know to perform basic administration of an AD infrastructure can be found at http://www.petri.co.il/ I suggest you start there.

Comment: Is something incorrect or not helpful here?

Comment: No, seems like a stupid downboat to me. +1 from this guy.